# How can We print pdf/Image from iPad using ipad programming

Tags: ipad, pdf, ios, printing

how can we print pdf.image from ipad using cocoa programming..any idea? which version of ipad support this feature

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately printing PDFs and single images is pretty easy. Check out the **[Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html)** -- I linked right to the printing section. Scroll down to where it says **Printing Printer-Ready Content**: the example shows how to print a PDF.

Printing requires iOS 4.2.